# Package builder unable to add Oracle.Data.Access.dll in tibco spotfire

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tibco, tibco-rv, tibco-gi

I am developing a custom package in Visual Studio 2010. This package can connect to oracle DB (read, write some data). For this functionality I need to reference Oracle.Data.Access.dll (64bit) and Oracle client installed. I found it under the `C:\oracle\odp.net\bin\4\` folder. When I develop a console application everything works fine. But when I try to validate and save my extension in package builder I get this error:

> Cannot create assembly from file C:...\Oracle.Data.Access.dll. The file is not a valid .NET assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. Just using system.data.oracleclient assembly for this purpose. It is working perfectly with tibco package builder and tibco player.